# Не удается получить результат с POST метода Java Spring

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

```
    @Query("SELECT n.clientLastName FROM NowClientHardware n WHERE n.clientLastName=?1")
    List<Object[]> fetchLastNames(String clientLastName);
```

Объект который хочу получить Rest сервисом

```
@RequestMapping(value = "clients/lg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public NowClientHardware findClientLogin(@RequestParam(value = "lg") String lg){
        return nowClientHardwareRepository.searchByLogin(lg);
    }
```

Получаю такую ошибку 
[org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'lg' is not present]

Comment: А вы как запрсо отправляете? ".../clients/lg?lg=SOMETEXT"

Comment: В postman указываю линк .../clients/lg  и передаю в body параметы  {'lg':'123}'

Comment: RequstParam - параметр, указанный в пути, то есть  ".../clients/lg?lg=123" должно пройти. Чтобы получтиь данные из POST запроса, нужен RequestBody, который нужно замапить на объект и только оттуда получтиь нужный параметр. Погуглите эти две аннотации с примерами

Comment: может так получится... поменяйте на это value = "clients/{lg}"  и @PathVariable(name = "lg")